# How to show/hide custom field in Redmine accordingly to issue status

Tags: redmine

I would like to show some custom field in Redmine only if issue status is closed.
(I want to log some "close reason"  information)

Comment: Why can't the "close reason" simply go in the body of the update?

Answer (score 2):

So would I but Redmine does not support this. You can monitor [Feature #8050](http://www.redmine.org/issues/8050) which is asking for this capability.

Answer (score 1):

See this redmine issue: http://www.redmine.org/issues/12005

It is a patch working with Redmine 2.3.x allowing hiding custom fields depending on the state transition.

I am currently adapting it to Redmine 2.4.x and will be posting soon at the same link as above.